# python ctypes + OCCI error

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I trying to test using python ctypes with a small C++ program that uses Oracle OCCI to see if it's possible to use such a combination. It compiles to an .so library file ok but I am getting a nice linker error when I try to use it from Python, I think:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "occi.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace oracle::occi;


static string userName = "****";
static string passWord = "****";
static string connectString = "****";

class Account{
        public:
                bool updateAccount(){ 
                        bool updated = false;
                        try{
                                Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
                                Connection *conn = env->createConnection(userName,passWord,connectString);
                                Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement("select * from test");
                                ResultSet *rs = stmt->executeQuery();
                                while(rs->next()){
                                        cout<<rs->getString(1)<<endl;
                                        cout<<rs->getString(2)<<endl;
                                        cout<<rs->getString(3)<<endl;
                                }
                                conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
                                env->terminateConnection(conn);
                                Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
                        }catch(...){
                        }
                        return updated;
                }
};

extern "C" {
        Account* Account_new(){ return new Account(); }
        bool Account_updateAccount(Account* account){ account->updateAccount(); }
}
```

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.6

import ctypes
import os

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.getcwd()+'/occi.so')

class Account(object):
        def __init__(self):
                self.obj = lib.Account_new()
        def updateAccount(self): 
                lib.Account_updateAccount(self.obj)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        a = Account()
        b = a.updateAccount()
        print str(b)
```

Error when I run ctest.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ctest.py", line 7, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/oracle/ctypes/occi.so')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ld.so.1: python2.6: fatal: relocation error: file /oracle/ctypes/occi.so: symbol _ZN6oracle4occi11Environment17createEnvironmentENS1_4ModeEPvPFS3_S3_jEPFS3_S3_S3_jEPFvS3_S3_E: referenced symbol not found
```

Any ideas, could it be an issue with using the Oracle Instant Client libs. I have seen weird issues with these in the past when trying to compile other 3rd party libraries against them ?

Thanks

Comment: It might be easier to use cx_Oracle <http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Python> which has doe all this for you

Comment: I need the Oracle connection side of it to be in a binary, probably obfuscated ultimately too, hence using C++ for this part. Thanks

Comment: Ok, looks like you cant use GCC/G++ for Solaris and Oracle as the Oracle library binaries were compiled using the SUN CC compiler. So I am recompiling everything (Python and OCCI program) with the SUN CC compiler.

Comment: Pah - ctypes doesn't compile with SUN C++. Apparently relies on GNU GCC/G++ libffi. http://psf.upfronthosting.co.za/roundup/tracker/issue2552 so much for this idea.